# Renaming Variables in HASH merge in SAS

Tags: hash, merge, sas, rename

I was trying to learn HASH joins in SAS but I am stuck on the case where I have multiple tables with the same variable names (not for the key, that's okay, but the other variables)

I want to join tables A, B and C each with two variables Key and Dat. The name Key and Dat is common in all three

This syntax works for me if I rename Dat in all three tables before hand to DAT_A, DAT_B, DAT_C but that defeats the purpose since I have to call all three tables which takes time

This code works:

```
data merged(keep=KEY DAT_A DAT_B DAT_C);
if 0 then
    set A B C;

if _N_ = 1 then
    do;
        declare hash A(dataset:'A');
        A.defineKey('KEY');
        A.defineData('DAT_A');
        A.defineDone();
        declare hash B(dataset:'B');
        B.defineKey('KEY');
        B.defineData('DAT_B');
        B.defineDone();
    end;

set C;

if A.find(key:KEY) = 0 and B.find(key:KEY) = 0 then
    output; run;
```

Its mentioned on the SAS website that you can specify options in data in the hash declare so I thought this might work

```
data merged(keep=KEY DAT_A DAT_B DAT_C DAT);
if 0 then
    set A B C;

if _N_ = 1 then
    do;
        declare hash A(dataset:'A (rename=(DAT=DAT_A))');
        A.defineKey('KEY');
        A.defineData('DAT_A');
        A.defineDone();
        declare hash B(dataset:'B (rename=(DAT=DAT_B))');
        B.defineKey('KEY');
        B.defineData('DAT_B');
        B.defineDone();
    end;

set C (rename=(DAT=DAT_C));

if A.find(key:KEY) = 0 and B.find(key:KEY) = 0 then
    output; run;
```

However running this gives the following error

> ERROR: Variable DAT is not on file WORK.A.
>
> ERROR: Hash data set load failed at line 33 column 4.
>
> ERROR: DATA STEP Component Object failure.  Aborted during the EXECUTION phase.

Does anyone have any ideas

Thanks a lot

Comment: In your first example, you already renamed DAT to DAT_A, DAT_B, and DAT_C. Did you not recreate datasets A, B, and C prior to running the 2nd example? Check that the variables are not already renamed.

Answer (score 2):

You are including `DAT` in the `keep=` dataset option on your output dataset. But your data step doesn't have the variable `DAT` anymore. You have renamed all copies of it.

Your error message about dataset `A` not having `DAT` is probably because of your earlier attempts to rename the variable to `DAT_A`.

Here is example using SASHELP.CLASS.

```
data merged ;
keep NAME AGE_A AGE_B AGE_C ;
if 0 then set
  sashelp.class(rename=(AGE=AGE_A))
  sashelp.class(rename=(AGE=AGE_B))
  sashelp.class(rename=(AGE=AGE_C))
;

if _N_ = 1 then do;
  declare hash A(dataset:'sashelp.class (rename=(AGE=AGE_A) where=(age_a ne 14))');
  A.defineKey('NAME');
  A.defineData('AGE_A');
  A.defineDone();
  declare hash B(dataset:'sashelp.class (rename=(AGE=AGE_B) where=(age_b ne 13))');
  B.defineKey('NAME');
  B.defineData('AGE_B');
  B.defineDone();
end;

set sashelp.class (rename=(AGE=AGE_C));

/* if A.find(key:NAME) = 0 and B.find(key:NAME) = 0 then output; */
if A.find(key:NAME) then call missing(age_a);
if B.find(key:NAME) then call missing(age_b);

run;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Tom. That worked. If I may ask, whats the difference between using "if A.find(key:NAME) = 0 and B.find(key:NAME) = 0 then output;" and "if A.find(key:NAME) then call missing(age_a);
if B.find(key:NAME) then call missing(age_b);"

Comment: In one you are using conditional OUTPUT statement to only write the matching records. In the other you keeping all observations. In that case you need to clear the variables that are sourced from the table that is not providing any records.  Because the variables are coming from a dataset they are retained and need to be explicitly reset to missing.

Comment: So kind of like inner join vs outer join?

Comment: Sort of. More like a SAS datastep MERGE with and without using IN= dataset options to check if both datasets are contributing. For one to one match they are the same.